# How many round trips or DB hits do PHP prepared statements cause?

Tags: php, mysqli

This may be the wrong part of StackOverFlow to ask this on but I'm curious... I have looked for about an hour asking google assorted questions and never finding an answer.  I have googled...

"PHP prepared statements number of round trips"

and about 20 other "tries" to find this information.  I did see a small chart a few weeks ago of the number of round trips say to do a simple select but as it sometimes happens I can't find that website again.

Basically, my PHP is very simplistic.  A simple...

1. database singleton (read or write)
2. a select, update, replace or insert for a SINGLE row at a time
3. close the stmt
4. in the destructor the singleton closes the DB connections

I think I remember reading it's 2 hits but I would just like to clarify.  Also, I am new to OOP programming so if my function is horrendously done and incorrect please let me know.  I know it works, but sometimes just because something works doesn't mean it's the proper way to design it.

Thank you!  Below is a sample of 1 function that's typical of my PHP class.

```
    # returns false on error, $numOfRows on success
# $NUD just needs to be of type array - passed by REFERENCE
public function FetchUserFromDB($username, &$NUD)
{
    if (DEBUGMODE) MyDebug::DebugMsgs('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--$username--<b>' . $username . '</b>');
    $query = 'SELECT ' . User::GetUserDBFields() . ' FROM UserDB WHERE username = ?'; // builds the SELECT and pulls in all fields from the User::GetUserDBFields function

    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->stmt_init(); // get the statement handle for prepared statements
        if ($stmt->prepare($query) === false) throw new Exception('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--prepare--FAILED--' . $stmt->error, 1);
        if ($stmt->bind_param("s", $username) === false) throw new Exception('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--bind_param--FAILED--' . $stmt->error, 1);
        if ($stmt->execute() === false) throw new Exception('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--execute--FAILED--' . $stmt->error, 1);
        if ($stmt->store_result() === false) throw new Exception('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--store_result--FAILED--' . $stmt->error, 1);
        if ($stmt->bind_result($NUD["user_id"], $NUD["username"], $NUD["company_name"], $NUD["f_name"], $NUD["l_name"], $NUD["street_num"], etc) === false) throw new Exception('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--bind_result--FAILED--' . $stmt->error, 1);

        $numOfRows = $stmt->num_rows(); // store the number of rows

        if ($numOfRows > 0) $stmt->fetch(); // only bother to fetch if there are more than 0 rows

        if (DEBUGMODE) MyDebug::DebugMsgs('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--fetch--$numOfRows=' . $numOfRows);

        $stmt->close();

        if (DEBUGMODE) MyDebug::DebugMsgs('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--fetch--$NUD["username"]=<b>' . $NUD["username"] . '</b>');
        return $numOfRows;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $stmt->close();
        if (DEBUGMODE) MyDebug::DebugMsgs('DB.php--FetchUserFromDB--**********' . $e->getMessage());
        return false; // error
    }
}
```

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trip to send the statement, one trip to send the bindvars and execute it..... but as you can then send different bindvars to the same statement (without needing to resend the statement) to execute it again with different arguments it makes a count of db trips slightly less meaningful..... and you only send the bind vars to the db at the point of execution, not for each individual bind var (that's buffered in the abstraction layer) –  Mark Baker 2 days ago

I have no way to give mark credit as he answered this as a comment.  I asked him to come here an answer this one so he would get credit but hasn't responded in 2 days so I thought I would answer it.  If an admin can give him the credit that would be great!

BTW - thank you Mark!